# How to make multiple elements as one object

Tags: javascript, html

I used multiple divs to create shapes in css and i want to combine them as one object in javascript to create a player and to be able to move the player with the arrow keys.I tried using the class property and made all them the same class name but it would not work.I just started to learn how to game develop in coding so i am not sure this code is even close to being correct.

What can i add to this code to make them on object/element?
  And how can i make all them move with together with the arrow keys?

```
 var playerHead = document.getElementById("playerHead");

    var playerMouth = document.getElementById("playerMouth");

    var playerOuterEye =document.getElementById("playerOuterEye");

    var playerInnerEye =document.getElementById("playerInnerEye");

    var playerBody = document.getElementById("playerBody");

    var playerArm = document.getElementById("playerArm");

    var playerLeg = document.getElementById("playerLeg");
```

So as you can see each of these elements are a shape made in css and I want to combine them all into one object so that i can make a player that moves with the arrow keys when pressed.

Comment: Could you share what this currently displays?

Comment: This sounds like you're looking for [`SVG`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG)...

Answer (score 0):

```
const player = {
   playerHead:  document.getElementById("playerHead"),
   playerMouth: document.getElementById("playerMouth"),
   playerOuterEye: document.getElementById("playerOuterEye")
}
```

and so on.
This way each value is a property of the play object.

As for moving something around the page, you will need to provide more information than that. We don't know what you are moving, or how you are trying to move it. Honestly it sounds like what you are trying to do is too complicated for css and some element selectors. I'd look into a real [js animation library](https://animejs.com/).

Comment: So how would this let OP move around all elements at the same time?

Comment: No idea, I'm answering the title of this question, as it relates to the code OP supplied. There's no sufficient information supplied to answer the rest.

Comment: Or shorter: `const player = Object.assign(...["playerHead", "playerMouth", "playerOuterEye",` … `].map((key) => ({[key]: document.getElementById(key)})))`. But it’s still unclear what the OP means by “as one object” and how they imagine the object to be able to “move together”.

Comment: Then I guess delaying an answer until further clarification would be better than "answering the title"...

Comment: i am trying to make my first ever 2d game and i was trying to make multiple shapes as one and move all the shapes together and when i press the arrow keys on the keyboard the move the same direction at the same time so i can add a custom player to the game.

Comment: @JosephBonello Right, but if you don't have a starting point on what you are going to move, and how you are going to move it, we can't really help.

Comment: if you mean by starting point by what i want to use..i was thinking on moving those objects with if, else, keycode and document.addEventListener and i just can't get it to work on all the objects at the same time. Is that what you mean as starting point? Like i said, i am just starting to learn how to code in javascript.

Comment: But is your plan to use js to change the absolute position style of an element?
I can update my answer for something like this, but I really do need to know what exactly you are moving. Are these elements divs with ascii art? One image? 7 Images?

Comment: the elements are divs ascii art, and yes i am planing to use js to change the absolute position of the divs with the arrow keys. each div i created is a separate element and combined together so i can move them all as one element or object.

Comment: Then you need to provide code of your attempt at that. A hint though, you'll want to wrap each of your parts with a parent element, that way you only need to move one element, everything inside it will move together.